# Truncate parameter before newline

Tags: strings, xstring, parameters

I want to truncate (cut/shorten) a string that contains newline (`\\` or `\newline`) in such a way that only the first line remains.

My problem is, that I use the `todonotes` package and have command wrapped around the normal `\todo`. Here is a minimal working example: (my actual command is more complex)

```
\newcommand{\TODO}[2]{\todo[#1,inline, caption={#2}]{#2}}
```

The problem is, that I might call that function with something that contains a newline. This will fail while setting the caption. Also, it is a bad idea to have a multi-line caption.

```
    \TODO{foo \\ bar}
```

Therefore I want to truncate the string first. I tried the `xstring` package, but I can not find anything on how to do it for newline (`\\` or `\newline`). I could use xstring to cut the string after x characters, but I do not know how soon the `\\` will happen.

Comment: you haven't provided a test file but I assume `caption={\zz#2\\\relax}` works were `\zz` is defined by `\def\zz#1\\#2\relax{#1}`

Comment: \let\newline=\relax ?  Not sure if that would work on \\ though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `\TODO` has an optional argument for specifying possible other options to `\todo` and a mandatory argument, which you want to truncate only in the list of todos, here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\TODO}{ O{} m }
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \masgo_todo:nfn { #1 } { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \masgo_todo:nnn
 {
  \todo[inline, caption={#2}, #1]{#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \masgo_todo:nnn { nf }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listoftodos

\section{Test}

First\TODO{x}

Second\TODO{x \\ y}

Third\TODO{x \\ y \\ z}

\end{document}
```

The mandatory argument is split at `\\` and then the first item is used for the caption, while the whole argument is used for the note.

[image]

Comment: First, let me thank you and second: Why does this work? What magic happens between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`? (And why doesn't Google find anything useful about the commands you use there?)

Comment: @masgo Essentially, it is “split off the mandatory argument whatever comes from the first ``\\`` and use it for the caption. Doing it with a sequence is not the only way, but, as you see, it just requires very short code and it allows for further modifications: it would be easy to change the ``\\`` into spaces for getting the full caption without line breaks.

Comment: Can you point me to some resource that explains the commands you use (`\seq_set_split:Nnn` `\l_tmpa_seq` `\seq_item:Nn` `\cs_new_protected:Nn` `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`). Google just gives me more stackoverflow answers that use them without explaination. The only thing I could find is `\ExplSyntaxOn` and the xparse documentation that explains `NewDocumentCommand`

Comment: @masgo On your TeX system you should be able to do `texdoc interface3` and `texdoc xparse` (or go to http://texdoc.net)

Comment: I found out, that the solution does not work if I have a new paragraph in my todo note (two consecutive new lines leading to a \par .. or simply a \par) .. I tried to change `\NewDocumentCommand{\TODO}{ O{} m }` to `\NewDocumentCommand{\TODO}{ O{} +m }` according to the xparse documentation this should make the command also parse paragraphs, but somehow it does not.

Comment: @masgo If I use `+m`, I have no problem. Please, ask a new question with a full example.